# How to extract all info on PDF bookmarks using GhostScript?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, pdftk

Is there a method of dumping all info on the bookmarks of a PDF using GhostScript?

With PDFtk I could use `pdftk in.pdf dump_data`, but is it possible to do it with GS?

I have a PDF with bookmarks where pdftk reports all bookmarks having `BookmarkPageNumber: 0`. I need to merge such PDFs and have the bookmarks still work with some additional bookmarks as well. I thought I would simply extract the destination page and rebuild the bookmarks but I FAIL because of `BookmarkPageNumber: 0`. The original PDF bookmarks do work but after merging they fail.

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having similar issue

Comment: I found that this problem is listed on issue tracker as well: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3275